# C++ pass by pointer

Tags: c++

Guys, I am very new to c++. I have just wrote this class:

```
class planet
{
public:
 float angularSpeed;
 float angle;
};
```

Here is a function trying to modify the angle of the object:

```
void foo(planet* p) 
{
  p->angle = p->angle + p->angularSpeed;
}

planet* bar = new planet();
bar->angularSpeed = 1;
bar->angle = 2;
foo(bar);
```

It seem that the angle in bar didn't change at all.

Comment: You're passing it by pointer; not reference. And it should work.

Comment: can you show a bit more of your code? how are you examining bar afterwards?

Comment: This looks correct, the bug is elsewhere.

Comment: @Yang - seeing is believing - step thru your code in the debugger watching the target angle field on each step.

Comment: I guess you're new to OOP, rewrite this as `void planet::foo()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you are passing `bar` by pointer, not by reference. Pass-by-reference would look like this:

```
void foo(planet& p)  // note: & instead of *
{
    p.angle += p.angularSpeed;   // note: . instead of ->
}
```

Pass-by-reference has the added benefit that `p` cannot be a null reference. Therefore, your function can no longer cause any null dereferencing error.

Second, and that's a detail, if your `planet` contains only public member variables, you could just as well declare it `struct` (where the default accessibility is `public`).

PS: As far as I can see it, your code *should* work; at least the parts you showed us.

Comment: That's not how you do a reference in standard C++.  Well, after your ninja edit it is.

Comment: At the time of my comment, your code was `void foo(planet% p)`.  Your ninja-d version is correct.

Comment: That's a relief.  I was expecting a cascading -1 to my own answer, and imminent insanity

Comment: A typo, I guess. In my keyboard both symbols are close.

Comment: _@Ben_: Yes, I initially mistyped the `&`. I corrected as quickly as I could, but apparently that still wasn't quick enough for noone to notice... :)

Comment: @stakx - Yep, StackOverflow is a harsh mistress for the occasionally fat-fingered (slef inclufed)

Comment: I'm fairly sure the comment also had a `%`, which makes fat-fingering somewhat less likely.  Perhaps `/clr` was in effect when stakx got up this morning?

Comment: _@Ben_: Nah, I've never actually used C++/CLI. The comment didn't have a `%`, but my original answer *did*. Never mind -- it was a very simple typo, due to my writing on a tiny netbook at the moment.

Comment: Ok, just that fact that `%` would have been valid in C++/CLI made me wonder.

Comment: @stakx - +1 to your comment, for not using C++/CLI, ever.

Answer (score 3):

Appearances must be deceptive because the code should result in `foo(bar)` changing the contents of the `angle` field.

btw this is not passing by reference, this is passing by pointer.  Could you change the title?

Passing by reference (better) would be

```
void foo(planet& p) {
p.angle += p.angularSpeed;
}

planet bar;
bar.angularSpeed=1;
bar.angle=2;
foo(bar);
```

You might also consider a constructor for `planet` that takes as parameters the initial values of `angle` and `angularSpeed`, and define a default constructor that sets them both to 0.  Otherwise you have a bug farm in the making due to unset values in `planet` instances.